# How would "no gods, no kings" be written in Italian

Tags: word-usage

I've seen it in Latin, and not too many other languages, would it be “niente dei non re?”

Comment: Welcome on ItalianSE!!!

Comment: Could you clarify what do you mean with the expression? Maybe giving some context...

Comment: Where is it used in Latin?

Comment: Referring to no religion, atheism. Not following social standards or cults.

Comment: @Jennifer: Yes, of course, sorry: I meant, is it from some famous Latin author? If so, we might check how it has been translated in its context. How is it in Latin?

Comment: I've found the following threads about this topic: https://www.reddit.com/r/latin/comments/1u7d0e/need_some_help_with_a_translation/ and https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-correct-Latin-translation-for-no-gods-no-masters-no-master-race

Comment: Yes, that is where I found it in latin, amongst other sites as well. I was curious about the correct Italian translation in writing,  I saw a good answer. But it seems to have disappeared.

Comment: Hi Jennifer, so it is not a phrase that comes from Latin ... right?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I have seen searching on Google, "No Gods, no kings, only man" is a quote from the videogame "Bioshock"; I think it states the absolute value of freedom and that every man is the supreme ruler of himself and does not need authorities (moral or political) tho whom delegate this power. Possibly a reference to the [anarchist labour slogan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_gods,_no_masters) "No God, no master".

Possible Italian translations could be:

> Niente dei, nessun re

or

> Né dei, né re

or slightly different:

> Nessun dio, nessun re

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't use the upper caps: they are indeed used when mentioning the single deity in the context of a monotheistic religion, and in formal contexts to mention the monarch. But here we are mentioning generic gods and kings, so they seem unnecessary.

Comment: Let me add the possibility “Niente dei, niente re” too.

Comment: @DaG I thought of that, too but _niente re_ sounded odd to me (personal opinion)

Comment: I thought so too. And trust me, I will not be using caps. This is actually for a tattoo for a client

Comment: My favorite of the proposals is the second. It's very idiomatic and conveys immediately the message.

Comment: @DenisNardin I prefer the third one instead (_Nessun dio, nessun re_) : it sounds deeper and communicates the idea that there is (have to be) none at all, not even only one. With `né <plural>... né <plural>` you can leave open the possibility that there is at least one (one God and/or one king)...